# NativeScript e2e tests - check value fo the switch component

Tags: mobile, cucumber, appium, nativescript, e2e-testing

I am using NativeScript-Dev-Appium for writing E2E tests for my NativeScript application and I want to access the value of the checked attribute of my Switch component.
I tried both

```
UiElement.getAttribute("selected"), UiElement.getAttribute("checked")
```

But it doesnt seem to access those attributes. 
Appium docs mentions to have incorporated isSelected() function for such elements.

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/selected/

This method is not available with this plugin. Is there a way to go about it?

Comment: Did you try `.getAttribute('value');`?

Comment: Yes. Thats the first one I did. Didn't work. Looks like a current limitation of the plugin.